# Android 12 reading file on Internal storage leads to "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Tags: android, file, kotlin, storage

after hours of headache and researching (even the second site of google :) ), I decided to ask here for a solution to my problem.

What I'm trying to do is reading a Keepass File from my Internal Storage. The file is located under "/storage/emulated/0/Keepass". The file has to remain there, because it automatically syncs with a SynologyNAS. When im trying to open the file with the absolute path, I get the exception

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The KeePass database file could not be found. You must provide a valid KeePass database file.
W/System.err:     at de.slackspace.openkeepass.KeePassDatabase.getInstance(KeePassDatabase.java:116)
W/System.err:     at de.philslr.passtick.MainActivity.readDb$lambda-5(MainActivity.kt:135)
W/System.err:     at de.philslr.passtick.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$1TiGYGtdMnuJx-_iduNC5-Ge9ag(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at de.philslr.passtick.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Keepass/passwords_ps.kdbx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:575)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
W/System.err:     at de.slackspace.openkeepass.KeePassDatabase.getInstance(KeePassDatabase.java:113)
W/System.err:   ... 11 more
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:567)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:273)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:567)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7756)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:561)
W/System.err:   ... 13 more
```

And the code to read the file is:

```
try {
            val file = File(path)
            val database = KeePassDatabase.getInstance(file).openDatabase("password")
            val entries = database.entries
            for (entry in entries) {
                Log.d("[KDBX Read]", "Entry: ${entry.title}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Couldn't open database, there was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I know there were some changes, to the file management with Android 12, but I guess there has to be a way to read the file anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: After File exists() use File canRead() before you try to read.

Comment: Put your file path in your code. Assign it to your path variable

Comment: I already tried it with putting the file path in my code and it doesn't work either. Same error. And what's the difference with canRead() it also tells me that it can't read the file, or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: If canRead() returns false you should not even try to load the database. Adapt your code. Make it robust.

Comment: `tried it with putting the file path in my code and it doesn't work either. ` ??? No that wil not solve a problem. But it would make your code better readable for us.

Comment: Yeah but how could I read the database? There must be a possibility. And I guess canRead() will return false, because it's a .kdbx file. Or is it just checking if the file is accessible

Answer (score 0):

> The file is located under "/storage/emulated/0/Keepass".

You do not have read/write access to that location.

> And the code to read the file is

It is unclear where you are getting `KeePassDatabase` from. If it is from [this discontinued library](https://github.com/cternes/openkeepass), there is another form of `getInstance()` that takes an `InputStream`. If that is available to you, you could go with the Storage Access Framework: use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` to let the user choose the document, then use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the `Uri` that you get back.

Comment: Okay thanks, yes this is the library I'm using. So the solution you told me, is when the user has to select the database everytime, but I want the user to select it once and then open it automatically on launch. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: @philxws692: Call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` when you get the `Uri`. Then, save the `Uri` somewhere (e.g., as a string in `SharedPreferences`). `takePersistableUriPermission()` gives you long-term access to the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: I tried this solution now and it gives me the error ```java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Keepass/passwords_ps.kdbx from pid=26483, uid=10720 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs```

Comment: @philxws692: Are you sure that you called `takePersistableUriPermission()` as soon as you get the `Uri`? If yes, then you might want to open a fresh Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] for this specific problem.

Comment: I think that I called it right... I called it in the `onActivityResult` method with `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`